# Out of Stack Space with IE9 and ExtJS 4.0

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4.0 which works on all browsers except for internet explorer 9. I am getting the error:

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
ext-all.js, line 1 character 354281
```

Has anyone encountered this before? 
If so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem but I have to add that I only encountered it with IE9 in compatibility mode.

The error pointed to a line that dealt with a component style. From there I noticed that I had a conflicting config option (the child component had a width that was greater than the parent component).

Yours could probably be caused by a different conflict but that was what was causing my problem.

Comment: This helped me, was getting same error in IE10\11 with ExtJS 3.4.x. I also had compat mode on, but forgot, until I came across this post :)

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to switch to `ext-all-debug.js` so that you can get a proper line number, then go from there. Ext 4 should support IE 9, so not sure what the issue would be without more details.